# Stuck in a "Help us protect your account" page loop with enabled MFA

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am an administrator with enabled MFA in my own Azure B2C tenant. And suddenly one day I was not able to sign in to that tenant. Just stuck on the page "Help us protect your account". Buttons "Next" and "Skip for now..." just redirect back to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check in my environment for this same error this error may occur if your administrator has `enabled the security defaults as 'yes'` on your tenant or alternatively you can use Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication using the ***Microsoft Authenticator app using notifications.***
[image]

To get rid of the screen you can disable security defaults like below:
***Go to azure portal ->azure active directory ->properties ->manage security defaults -> NO -> save as below***

[image]

***After disabling security default, I am able to access on the page successfully as below***

[image]

***Reference:*** [multi-factor authentication (MFA) and blocking legacy authentication.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults)